# check if values of two columns are same and then fill with nan in one of those columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose my df looks like:

```
Col A          Col B
red             red
blue            pink
green           green
orange          green
black           black
```

my output should be:

```
Col A          Col B
red              nan
blue             pink
green            nan
orange           green
black            nan
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Series.mask`:

```
df['Col B'] = df['Col B'].mask(df['Col A'] == df['Col B'])

    Col A  Col B
0     red    NaN
1    blue   pink
2   green    NaN
3  orange  green
4   black    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

I really like the Series.mask method in the accepted answer, but I thought I'd try with the .apply method as well:

```
df['ColB'] = df.apply(lambda x:  np.NaN if x['ColA']==x['ColB'] else x['ColB'], axis=1)
```